# How to get current events from google calendar API?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API method [gapi.client.calendar.events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to retrieve events on the calendar *now*.

I can successfully filter on start date and end date. But, filtering on things that start today doesn't help me if an event started yesterday and is still on-going.

```
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'my calendar id',
      // shows things that have not yet started
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });
```

How do I find the list of things on a calendar that are currently going on?

I'd (obviously) like to avoid pulling a week's worth of events and parsing through it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way of querying for the current event directly, but you can certainly give it a limited min and max time, so you'll only have a small number of events to search through. If your events are regular and of predictable duration, you may be able to make it just give you one.

```
events = client.events().list(calendarId='primary',
                              timeMin='2011-12-22T09:00:00Z',
                              timeMax='2011-12-22T22:00:00Z').execute()
```

For more information, please read the Official Documentation of Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?csw=1

Comment: Yes, but that won't help me if there is an event going on now that starts before my timeMin. For example, if there's a week long event that started two days ago and I set the timeMin to the start of today, I won't see the week long event.

Answer (score 0):

So I came to this thread in search of the same answer but to no avail, So here's what you can do :

```
    $data = self::$service->events->listEvents(self::$calendarId, $optParams);
    $curr_time = time();
    $active_meetings = array();

    if (count($data->getItems()) > 0) {  
        foreach ($data->getItems() as $event) {
            $start = date("U", strtotime($event->start->dateTime));
            $end   = date("U", strtotime($event->end->dateTime));
            if(($start > $curr_time) && ($end < $curr_time))
            {
                $active_meetings[$event->id] = $event->summary;
            }   
        }
    }
    return $active_meetings;
```

Here just taking events back to 1 hour before to events till 1 hour after and then comparing their start time and end time to current time.

This will list current ongoing events. Thanks

Comment: Why are you evalutating if `$start` is greater than `$curr_time`? This will return events that hasn't started yet.