# How to get today's events from Google Calendar in Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to display any events for the current day in my app (associated with the user's Google account) So this means ANY calendar that has been made on their Google account.

I need to retrieve information about each event such as TITLE, DESC, TIME

I've looked to see what's already out there, but I'm struggling to find ones that specify the date of the events wanted and how to do it without calendarID and eventID as those defeat the purpose of what I want to do.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) since you cannot get the current events directly.

You can set the `timeMin` and `timeMax` from the start of the current date up to the last hour of the said date.

You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981480/how-to-get-current-events-from-google-calendar-api) for further info.

Comment: Thanks very much!